# Problem running logstash in aws ec2 linux ami

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash

I am setting up **"elasticsearch"** in AWS, i am trying to use AWS linux AMI. When i run the

```
bin/logstash -f "/path to config file"
```

i get error saying:
"logstash.yml" not found try using "--path.settings"
then when i use

```
"--path.settings="/etc/logstash"
```

i again get another error.

I have been following this document of AWS

> https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/resources/articles/logstash-tutorial/

The error i get after specifying

```
--path.settings="/etc/logstash" :
"Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}"
```

I have configured file **logstash_simple.conf**, specifying input and output.
 this is the command line input in the linux ec2 instance

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/logstash_simple.conf 
--path.settings="/etc/logstash"
```

Comment: Share your logstash_simple.conf

Answer (score 0):

Okay i had made a mistake in the config file,
i missed providing aws accesskey and secret key, dumb me!